# open vpn with a portable client

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I have decided to try a VPN solution rather than reverse SSH to access my files at home from any public PC. I have a thread I started earlier but now have been informed that there is a better option.

I have contacted openvpn forums and they inform me that there is no portable client out there. Now I'm not sure how to setup what I need .

Here is the response by the openvpn forums:

---

> > Tue Dec 10, 2019 3:27 am
> >     So if there is no portable vpn client , then how do i connect to my PC from anywhere, such as a public PC at a library that i do not
> >     have admin rights to install any drivers, software etc?
>
> You don't connect. You cannot use openvpn in such circumstances ..
>
> Edit: You know, you could ask your library to install openvpn for you,
>   that would work. And hey, it's a library, they are all for freedom of
>   speech, right ?
>
> Have a nice day

---

Very sarcastic about my question.

I have a feeling to post it here and have professionals who actually want to help guide me in the process.

So to recap, as to make sure my question is on topic:

1.I would like to do a VPN solution with a portable client so I can access my files from my Win10 Home PC
 2. I need some guidance on how to do so since I have never setup said VPN

Comment: They're not wrong, I don't think. In my experience VPN must operate at a privileged level with your OS. It must tell the OS it is a valid network connection, and they define the traffic that must be tunneled through it. This usually involves drivers and other elements that must communicate with the OS. Portable apps have very limited rights on the systems they run on and so are appropriate for applications that USE things from the OS but don't necessarily PROVIDE things TO the OS. I may be wrong, but I don't think I am. Portable apps have their purpose, but VPN isn't one of them.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Using a VPN is something that typically requires being an Administrator.  There does not appear to be a current portable OpenVPN client.  Any results I found are outdated and insecure.

Comment: hmm, well, i know i was informed by Art and Ectasy on the last thread that there is indeed a portable vpn client. Like question 1 states above: i would like to access my files from home on any public pc using a VPN and portable vpn client as per suggested in the last thread:)

Thanks.

If a portable VPN client is a myth, then what other options do i have? @music2myear I agree, they may not be wrong but their delivery was sure not the best for a new user haha. anyway. i would love to know what Art and Ectasy were speaking of. I hope they chime in:)

Comment: The client is portable. The TAP-Win32 driver is not. // You should ask yourself whether granting unfettered access to your home PC/network from third-party computers is really what you want. If you just need some files, why not use something like OneDrive or Dropbox?

Comment: @DanielB I feel ya. Im doing this so i can learn, and also to keep my files on my own system.  As for access from third party pc's, that wouldnt really matter since im the one with the private key and no one else, its the same as sftp except vpn instead. once i disconnect, then the pc cant reconnect to mine without the client and key correct?

Comment: You lose control the moment you plug your USB thumb drive into the PC you want to use your VPN on.

Comment: yes, while i am on that pc, but once i disconnect, the vpn tunnel is closed, nothing can get in unless somehow i used an infected computer at school or the library, which would really be terrible. i see your point with that. even using sftp from a public pc i guess could be a risk of the same thing? Am i following your thinking? thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a Portable OpenVPN. Just visit the link below:

https://github.com/portapps/openvpn-portable/releases

Before you run the program:

1. Create the folder "data", followed by the folder "config" (e.g., X:\OpenVPN\data\config)
2. Run the installer tap-windows.exe to install the TAP Windows Adapter (if it somehow tells you that it failed installing, just restart your computer)

The only caveat I can think of this portable OpenVPN, is that it doesn't support TLS 1.3. The other portable OpenVPN (I know of) that is capable of supporting TLS 1.3 is rather outdated and you have to manually update the OpenSSL and OpenVPN files.